# Save WAL-files to remote Server continuously

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, cron, postgresql

I have got a Postgresql Database and I activated archive-mode. The Wal files are saved at a location at the server.  How can I save this files to a backup-server(ssh). Is it a good practise to start a rsync job every minute with cron.
Kind Regards!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html http://www.pgbarman.org/ https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e

Answer (score 0):

You can use some utils:
 * [pgBarman](https://github.com/2ndquadrant-it/barman), run on the foreign server. Good [actricle](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-restore-and-migrate-postgresql-databases-with-barman-on-centos-7).
 * [wel-e](https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e), run on the DB server, maintain s3 storage.

PS: this loos will help to 'Save WAL-files to remote Server continuously'.

Comment: How des this answer the question?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens this loos will help to 'Save WAL-files to remote Server continuously', no?